# Restrict any new installation of already published google-marketplace-app

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

We have a google-marketplace-app which is already published and actively used by consumers. But there is a new requirement, where we need to block any new installations of the app without impacting the existing consumers.

Is there a straight forward option to achieve this? Or do we have to unpublish existing app and republish with some specific options (i.e: "visibility-options")?

The ideal expectation from our perspective is not to let existing app consumers/domain-admins to perform anything on this regard. But only that existing domains needs to whitelisted from our end (by app developers) to allow installation of the app to admins of those domains, where as any other domains shouldn't have install access (even with direct app installation link).

Appreciate any recommendations on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Chrome Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) there is an option to add trusted testers to the app. The accounts that are in that list will have the visibility to the application. 
You can also create a group and add that group to the list, and the people inside that group will also have visibility to the app.
[Here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#testaccounts) you can find the documentation related to this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We've tried "private" visibility option (using both "private testers" approach as well as "google-group" approach) with a new test app and that works.  Adding to your answer, we've found that unpublishing the existing app doesn't impact existing users as it is not removing the app from them. And also the existing users will be automatically gets updated to new version after republishing the app. (reference: "Private" option description under visibility options of app settings in chrome webstore)